# How to make tomcat deploy webapp after tomcat start?

Tags: tomcat

I configured tomcat server.xml with *autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="start"*

when tomcat start , it will deploy webapp immediately. my webapp need about 3 minutes to start.

if *java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind* occurs, tomcat cannot handle any request but the tomcat process is still be there. 3 minutes was wasted.

if i configured *autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="false"* tomcat will deploy webapp after startup successfully. but i don't want tomcat to autoDeploy webapp if i edit some files in webapp.

how can i make tomcat only deploy webapp after start successfully, and don't re deploy webapp if file changes (*autoDeploy="false"*)